# Expand citations with bibtex or disable nested citations

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a paper like the following one, and bibtex creates cites inside of cites:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

cite1~\cite{abc:oopsla2005} 
cite2~\cite{martinAl:oopsla2005}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib,crossref}

\end{document}
```

Where bib.bib contains:

```
@InProceedings{martinAl:oopsla2005,
author = {Michael Martin and Benjamin Livshits and Monica S. Lam},
title = {Finding application errors and security flaws using {PQL}: a program query language},
crossref = {oopsla2005},
pages = {365--383},
}
```

and crossref contains:

```
@Proceedings{oopsla2005,
key = {OOPSLA 2005},
booktitle =  {Proceedings of the 20th {ACM SIGPLAN} Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005)},
title =      {Proceedings of the 20th {ACM SIGPLAN} Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005)},
year =      2005,
address =      {San Diego, California, USA},
month =        oct,
publisher =     acm,
note =         sigplan # {, 40(11)}       
}
```

So, when I create the pdf file, I get:

> [1] M. Martin, B. Livshits, M. S. Lam, Finding application errors and
>   security flaws using PQL: a program query language, in: **[3]**, pp.
>   365–383. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).
>
> [2] C. Allan, P. Avgustinov, A. S. Christensen, L. Hendren, S. Kuzins,
>   O. Lhot ́ak, O. de Moor, D. Sereni, G. Sittampalam, J. Tibble, Adding
>   trace matching with free variables to AspectJ, in: **[3]**, pp.
>   345–364. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).

where [3] is:

> [3] OOPSLA 2005, Proceedings of the 20th ACM SIGPLAN Conference on
>   Object-Oriented Programming Systems, Languages and Applications
>   (OOPSLA 2005), ACM Press, San Diego, California, USA, 2005. ACM
>   SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).

I would like to extend cites 1 and 2 to show the full content of these references. If I can show full references, I expect Latex/Bibtex removes reference 3.

Is it possible to set some parameters in Latex to achieve my goal? 
(I cannot use a line command option because my Latex file is compiled in the journal server)

In other words, I just want to get:

> [1] M. Martin, B. Livshits, M. S. Lam, Finding application errors and
>   security flaws using PQL: a program query language, in Proceedings of
>   the 20th ACM SIGPLAN Conference on Object-Oriented Programming
>   Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005), ACM Press, San
>   Diego, California, USA, 2005. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).
>
> [2] C. Allan, P. Avgustinov, A. S. Christensen, L. Hendren, S. Kuzins,
>   O. Lhot ́ak, O. de Moor, D. Sereni, G. Sittampalam, J. Tibble, Adding
>   trace matching with free variables to AspectJ, in Proceedings of the
>   20th ACM SIGPLAN Conference on Object-Oriented Programming Systems,
>   Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 2005), ACM Press, San Diego,
>   California, USA, 2005. ACM SIGPLAN Notices, 40(11).

Comment: If command line is not an option, you have to move the bibliographic information in the reference which is `crossref`ed in the other references.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). I think you need to increase the value of something like `mincrossrefs` to stop this process from occurring. However, it is a while since I used `bibtex` and I am not sure if it depends on your bibliographical style. It would help a very great deal if you would post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and suggest solutions when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi I edited the question to detail my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bibtex` has a command line switch (i.e., `min-crossrefs=<number>` to control the minimum number of a crossref is used to be included in the bibliography.

If one cannot control the option when `bibtex` is run, there are a few options.

You can run

```
bibtex -min-crossrefs=500 <file>
```

on your own computer to generate the bibliography in a `<file>.bbl` file, and then replace

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib}
```

with the content of the generated `.bbl` file, or by `\input{<file>.bbl}`.

A second option is to use `bibexport` to generate a `.bib` where all `crossref`s  have been resolved and their data is included in the (appropriate) entries. This can be achieved by the following:

```
bibexport -n -o new-bib.bib <file>
```

then `-n` is to remove the `crossref`ed entries from the bibliography, and `-o` is to give a name to the output, in this case `new-bib.bib`. Please use `texdoc bibexport` for full documentation of `bibexport`.

Then change

```
\bibliography{bib}
```

to

```
\bibliography{new-bib}
```